# Going to school for free while not being a permanent resident in Canada

Tags: canada, payment

I live in New Brunswick, Canada and I am not currently a permanent resident, so I have to pay 14,000 dollars for my school (currently in middle school). I was wondering if I could go to school for free by either using my academic skills or without them? i.e: I have a bronze medal in math olympiad and I won a math contest in Canada.

Comment: Find an appropriate scholarship of sufficient amount, then yes.  Otherwise, unlikely.